# How to display a SeekBar correctly? (layout_weight)

Tags: android-layout

I`m trying to create the following layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    </TextView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    </TextView>

    <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/seekbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </TextView>

</LinearLayout>
```

I`d like to give the 80% of the parent layout to the textView1 and textView2, wrap the SeekBar as much as possible and the rest of the free space give to the textView3.

I`ve tried to:

- use layout_weight attributes (respectively - 4, 4, 1, 1) but the last
  view overlaps the SeekBar
- use layout-weight only  with textView1 and textView2, set SeekBar`s height to "wrap_content" and set "match_parent" for the last view

And now I have no more ideas. Have you ever had such a problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well to create this layout I would try :

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dip"
    android:layout_weight="4" >
</TextView>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dip"
    android:layout_weight="4" >
</TextView>

<SeekBar
    android:id="@+id/seekbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dip"
    android:layout_weight="1">
</TextView>
```

make change on weights  tu adjust sizes.
let the seek bar to wrap content, give weight on other views.

tell me if that helps.

Comment: Great! Thank you! It works perfectly. But... Can you tell me why it works? Does the space for the SeekBar is determined at first (because it doesn't have any weight assigned)? And then the rest is divided according to weights?